# how to cut timestamp using Cut command upto a particular point?

Tags: unix, timestamp, db2, cut

I fetched timestamp sysibm.sysdummy. If the timestamp is 2015-08-21.23.35.45.45287 ,I need to cut it till the minutes only i.e. 2015-08-21.23.35. Can any one tell me how to cut this using unix commands?

Comment: Could you provide some more context on what you try to do and how you fetched the timestamp? Why did you use DB2 and not the Unix environment for that? Would it work to have DB2 return that needed part?

Comment: Basically I am using it for one automation and for that its a part of script that will fetch timestamp from sysibm.sysdummy and i hv to cut that timestamp upto minutes  and then use it again in one db2 command.   I am using this command: db2 "SELECT current timestamp FROM sysibm.sysdummy1"

Comment: Then why don't you write a stored procedure and leave the entire processing within DB2?

Comment: I cant because I am working on taking explain plan of stored procedures only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to `cut` it, use

```
echo '2015-08-21.23.35.45.45287' | cut -d"." -f1-3
```

Cut might not be the best solution, consider the DB2 expression (@data_henrik) or the shell built-in

```
a="2015-08-21.23.35.45.45287"; echo ${a:0:16}
```

Answer (score 0):

The DB2 expression `values(substr(timestamp(current timestamp),1,16))` would return the timestamp up to the minutes. It would be delivered by DB2, not by Unix.

Comment: this one is not working :(                                                                                          db2 "SELECT values(substr(timestamp(current timestamp),1,16)) FROM sysibm.sysdummy1"
SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "VALUES" of type "FUNCTION" having
compatible arguments was found.  SQLSTATE=42884
I got this error

Comment: just try `db2 "values(substr(timestamp(current timestamp),1,16))"` - it is the same as `db2 "SELECT substr(timestamp(current timestamp),1,16) FROM sysibm.sysdummy1"`

Comment: @KalpnaKashyap - warning, the value returned will be formatted according to the session setting, which may yield incorrect results if you're not careful.

Comment: Can u please elaborate a bit that wat are he possibilities?